# having issue printing data out to output file

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I'm having a problem with getting this code to print out to file due to some undefined behavior. It seems that when I test it the output file opened but was empty. can anyone run it on their system and tell me if it work on your system or is it not working at all. Also can you provide me with the output file if you run it.

here is the code
http://ideone.com/ku7qc
and the data for the file 
http://ideone.com/TY1U8
thanks

Comment: Please include a SHORT piece of code that reproduces your problem instead of linking to an external site where there are over 200 lines of code and no hint of what part you think is not working right.

Comment: You really do need to figure out how to compile and run programs on your own computer; asking ideone.com, your friend, and us, to try to debug everything that doesn't work is bound to be far more painful than just getting the right environment on your own computer in the first place.

Comment: actually the compiler doesn't show any problem with the code and i ask someone to run it before it work on their system, but it doesn't run on mine

Comment: "Doesn't run" doesn't begin to sound right. Your prompt is just returned to you immediately with no notice of terminated program or anything else funny? If it _really_ doesn't work well, run the thing under `valgrind` or `gdb` and spot the problem in action.

Comment: i don't know how to use those. I'm new to programming. I can only use vs

Comment: I think you should print the data before you do the sort, then after you do the sort, and then debug the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the code comments:

The compiler is supposed to be gcc, the `system("PAUSE")`  won't "work" in most UNIXes. It looks like it is meant to be compiled under cygwin running on a Windows PC, or under Linux.  Not Windows. The PAUSE part makes very little sense, since that is largely a DOS command.   You had to have copied the code from someone, it looks like the code scores competing ice skaters. The probability that it is production code is low.

Where did you get the code, and what assignment is this supposed to be for?

Suggestion:
See `www.cygwin.com`  to install cygwin on your PC.

Comment: well i always use system("PAUSE"); and there was never a problem before.

Comment: This code was not even written on a linux system which is very odd that it did not run on window and well I actualy wrote the code but I have some sample code from the professor to look as a reference, and I actually ask question about the code on here since i was only at the getdata function.